# What compilers can detect pure mathematical functions and optimize them (without telling you so)?

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction

I have seen that [GCC is not able to detect pure mathematical functions and it needs you to provide the attribute "const" to indicate that](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html).

What compilers can detect pure mathematical functions and optimize them (without telling you so)?

Answer (score 2):

To do so is inherently risky in languages that have pointers and lack global compilation & analysis.  So, if a an operation is declared non-const, the compiler must assume it could have side-effects.

Example:

```
//getx.cpp
int GetX(int input)
{
   int* pData = (int*) input;
   *pData = 50;
   return 0;
}
// gety.cpp
int GetY(int input)
{
   return GetX(input + 4);
}
// main.cpp
int main()
{
   int arg[] { 0, 4 };
   return GetY((int)arg);
}
```

The compiler while compiling `GetY` can't tell that `GetX` treats its argument as a pointer and dereferences and modifies data in a non-functional, side-effect-prone manner.  That information is only available during linking so you'd have to re-invent the concept of linking to include a lot of code generation and analysis to support such a feature.

Comment: Of course, if GetX is not pure mathematical then GetX is not as it calls a non pure mathematical function (maybe we should call them procedures). If a function calls an external function it should assume is not pure mathematical.

Comment: But the problem is that "external" means in a different translation unit (different .c file).  That's a big limitation.

Comment: No need to "reinvent", GCC's `-flto` option does optimization during the linking stage.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really (afaik) the *compiler* that does this, but when writing C# in Visual Studio when using the plugin ReSharper, you can get compile time hints that indicate that it is possible to declare something as `const`. On the other hand, that doesn't go under the category "without telling you so", so it might not be what you're looking for...

Comment: Of course, I would like the compiler be able to detect them automatically instead of having to use another external tool.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that gcc now does: doing "gcc -O2 -S" on the following code, and reading the assembly, the call to foo() from within test() is identified as pure and moved outside of the loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double __attribute__((noinline)) foo(double x)
{
    x = x + 1;
    x = x * x;
    if (x > 20)
        x -= 1;
    x -= x * x;

    return x;
}

void test(int iters, double x)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < iters; ++i) {
        printf("%g\n", foo(x));
    }
}
```

This is Fedora 22, gcc 5.1.1, x86_64.  I haven't tried, but with -flto, I would expect this to work across compilation units.

Also, it is worth noting that today gcc has the command line options -Wsuggest-attribute=pure and -Wsuggest-attribute=const.